# How can I change the RollingFileAppender to another than the one set in config file?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using log4j in my app, and a config file that sets up output to console and a rollingfileappender. Pasting config file below. Is there a way to change
the fileappender output file after opening the config file in code? It opens fine for me, but there are times when I will want to use a different output file than the default one in the config file. Thanks for any direction.

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, RFA

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] - %m %n

log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${user.home}/output.log

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep backup files
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=5

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] [%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] - %m %n
```

Comment: Do you mean in code, get the appender the config file setup for file output then use setFile ? That's what I'd like to do, but did not see a way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to edit the properties file from your code and have log4j detect it you'll have to make log4j monitor the properties file first by calling `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.properties")`

However, I'd prefer to access the appenders programatically using the `Logger` api like kunal mentioned.

update; code for doing it programatically

```
Enumeration allAppenders = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
while (allAppenders.hasMoreElements()) {
    Object object = (Object) allAppenders.nextElement();
    if (object instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
        RollingFileAppender appender = (RollingFileAppender) object;
        appender.setFile("/path/to/new/file.log");
        appender.activateOptions();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `appender.activateOptions();` is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

define another appender (with a different File value).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set (change) the File programmatically. Have a look at the [RollingFileAppender API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#setFile%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int%29).

```
public void setFile(String fileName,
                    boolean append,
                    boolean bufferedIO,
                    int bufferSize)
             throws IOException
```

> Sets and opens the file where the log output will go. The specified file must be writable.